# WildFly AS 8.0 Error: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator not a subtype

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly, broadleaf-commerce

I come from a heavy .NET/IIS background and although I have worked with Java in the past, I am fairly new to large Java web applications so please bear with me. Due to my limited background, I will walk through the steps I took from the very start trying to get this app to deploy (in case my "fix" for another issue could have broken something else).

I am having trouble deploying a Spring/Hibernate application to the WildFly application server. The application itself definitely works because it is a sample project in an open-source eCommerce framework (Broadleaf Commerce). I have also successfully got it to run on Jetty locally.

The application uses three JNDI data sources which I have configured in WildFly/JBoss; I have confirmed that the application sees them because I tried running it prior to configuring the DS's and it gave a clear error, which it no longer did after I configured them.

Afterwards, the application would throw three different errors (one per each PU) saying that it was unable to start the persistence units due to a class loading exception. This error I was able to fix by adding a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file into WEB-INF with the following contents (based on what I understand, this file is needed because this app has all of the Hibernate JARs within its WAR file already, and thus the below file tells JBoss not to supply its own Hibernate implementation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
           <module name="org.hibernate"/>
           <module name="org.javassist"/>
           <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" slot="main"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

After adding the above file, I now get this set of three (one per each PU) errors:

```
23:15:16,791 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."admin.war#blPU".__FIRST_PHASE__: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."admin.war#blPU".__FIRST_PHASE__: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator not a subtype
      service jboss.persistenceunit."admin.war#blSecurePU".__FIRST_PHASE__: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."admin.war#blSecurePU".__FIRST_PHASE__: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator not a subtype
      service jboss.persistenceunit."admin.war#blCMSStorage".__FIRST_PHASE__: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."admin.war#blCMSStorage".__FIRST_PHASE__: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator not a subtype
```

There is a file called hibernate-envers-4.1.11.Final.jar inside the WAR archive. Also remember that this is the same WAR (except the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file) which ran successfully on Jetty.

I tried poking around but simply have no idea where to look... I tried changing the DS's in WildFly to use a JDBC4-based driver as well as a JDBC41 (probably has nothing to do with it) with no luck. I know it is probably something very simple and is related to configuration (of either WildFly or the application itself), but I am not sure where to poke around.

My completely out of the blue take on it is that WildFly is still somehow trying to load an older version of Hibernate, which the classes in the bundled 4.1.11 Envers JAR are trying to override but cannot (or vice versa).

If it is of any use - the app is trying to connect to a PostgreSQL 9.3 database and the DS's defined in WildFly work as far as clicking "Test Connection" goes.

If there is any other info I can provide which would be helpful, please let me know.

Any insights or hints would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out the cause of the issue (but I am figuring it was a conflict with the JARs supplied by JBoss).

Just in case anyone is having the same issue - I ended up using Tomcat where everything worked without a hitch. I understand this isn't exactly a solution but it will work in the interim. This also possibly reinforces my initial suspicion of the JARs provided by JBoss conflicting with the bundled Hibernate JARs in the project.

Answer (score 2):

The Wildfly server has a Hibernate 4.3 version. To use Hibernate 4.1 you have to exclude the default Hibernate and package the correct one.

[Class Loading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.hibernate" />
        <module name="org.hibernate.envers" />
        <module name="org.hibernate.validator" />
        <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```