# Hibernate Envers Conflict

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

My application is based on Spring and Hibernate.

Recently we planned to use Hibernate Envers for data auditing.

We just added Enver dependency in project pom.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Our Spring version is 5.0.2.RELEASE and hibernate version is 5.2.12.Final.

We added @Audited annotation on one of our entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Audited
public class Employee implements Serializable {
```

Every thing worked fine.

We deployed our war on wildfly, but now when we call our REST services, response shows 200 HTTP Code but content is blank.

Here is the sample response

```
status: 200 OK
date: Wed, 03 Jan 2018 11:21:10 GMT
server: WildFly/10
connection: keep-alive
x-powered-by: Undertow/1
content-length: 0
```

System is also not logging any log statement which is part of this API method.

If we remove @Audited annotation, Rest API returns proper response.

We though its because of dependency conflict so we ran this maven command

mvn dependency:purge-local-repository

But it didnt work, We are not sure in which direction we should investigate it further.

Any guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: I would use a debugger and create exception breakpoint.

Comment: @ThomasEdwin We cant see any exception in logs.

Comment: Test your log. Throw exception intentionally.

Comment: For starters your `hibernate-envers` version should match the hibernate version. Also make sure that you have the auditing tables without it it won't work.

Comment: also note that Wildfly has its internal Envers version, so during runtime you might use a different version than 5.2.5. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519693/wildfly-as-8-0-error-org-hibernate-integrator-spi-integrator-provider-org-hibe